# Angular 8 add custom Request headers using HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, http-headers

In angular 8 HttpInterceptor to add custom  header is not working 
I need to add custom request header to my http function using HttpInterceptor

Hear my code from HttpInterceptor

```
intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler,
      ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const newRequest = req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('APIKey', 'YOUR-API Key-HERE'),
        });
        return next.handle(newRequest);


      }
```

The result is not correct as shown in the below image 
[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGtdP.jpg)

I need it as show on the below image

[valid request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E809F.jpg)

any help

Comment: Hi Atta, would you mind formatting your code? I did it for you the first time, but you changed it...

Answer (score 0):

Change

`return next.handle(req);`

to return your new request which contains the additional headers

`return next.handle(newRequest);`

Comment: thanks ,but i am return the  new request which contains the additional headers but  still not working